# Should navigating to a post in your inbox update your "responses" tab?

Tags: feature-request

If it's implemented as: if you click on your responses tab in you profile, then all the new numbers on the tab go  away, then I understand. It should be asked specifically for the case of "1 new response".

If I click on a notification on StackExchange, inbox.  When I later navigate to my profile page (it doesn't do this on MSO, but does on some other sites), there is still a bubble with a number of responses on the responses tab, even if it's only one -- and it's relatively obvious I viewed it.

Does that clarify it?

Comment: err... what? I'm not sure what you're asking for. Please clarify. Then it should probably be tagged as [tag:feature-request].

Comment: He's basically saying that viewing an item in your inbox should also mark it as unread in the list of unread items in the "responses" tab of your user profile.